# How should i evaluate the insert benchmark from CrateDB?

Tags: database, benchmarking, evaluate, crate, data-ingestion

I am trying to understand and interpret the benchmark which is provided from CrateDB. (https://staging.crate.io/benchmark/)

I am interested on how many elements can be inserted during one second.
I know that this may vary on the size of the tuples. And I would define that I have the same ements-sizes as CrateDB uses in their exmpale.

They provide an exmaple for bulk-insertion and there it takes on average 50 milliseconds to insert a bulk of 10.000 (integer/string pairs).

1. Now, can I calculate that it is possible to insert 20 bulks of 10.000 pairs during 1s (1000 milliseconds)?

   1000ms/50ms = 20 -> 20*10000 = 200000 -> 200000 integer/string pairs per second
2. Can I say how the result would differ, if i have 7 integers and  2 decimals(7,4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this: https://staging.crate.io/benchmark/ is only comparable to itself, so it will show if code changes/features made CrateDB slower/faster. It's not a reliable source for actual benchmarking and won't give you comparable numbers (among other things because the setup is vanilla).

As for your question, I recommend running your own benchmarks to satisfy whatever requirements you have.

The tool we used for these benchmarks is [cr8](https://github.com/mfussenegger/cr8) from one of our core devs!

Cheers, Claus